# I need to separate a integer then add the digits together in java

Tags: java

Good morning, I am on now to lesson 4 and am having a bit of trouble using loops. Please note that I have seen it resolved using strings but I am trying to grasp loops.

The reason for the trouble is I need to show both answers: The integer broken into individual number ex: 567 = 5 6 7

And then 567 = 18

I am able to get the integer added together but am not sure on how to separate the integer first and then add the individual numbers together. I am thinking that I need to divide down to get to 0. For instance if its a 5 digit number /10000, /1000, /100, /10, /1

But what if the user wants to do a 6 or 7 or even a 8 digit number?

Also I am assuming this would have to be first and then the addition of the individual integers would take place?

thanks for the guidance:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class spacing {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            int n;

            System.out.print("Enter a your number: ");

            n = in.nextInt();   

                  int sum = 0;          

                  while (n != 0) {

                        sum += n % 10;

                        n /= 10;

                  }
                  System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//I assume that the input is a string which contains only digits
public static int parseString(String input)
{
    char[] charArray = input.toCharArray();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < input.length; index++)
    {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(charArray[index] + "");
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Use the function above, pass your input to the function and use the output as you like.

Comment: This is homework. Please don't provide the complete solution.

Comment: hate to sound dumb but I have no idea what you mean by pass your input to the function

Comment: I mean that you have a string as input and in you function called main() call the function implemented above like this: parseString(input);

Comment: Lajos, thanks for the guidance but I am I haven't really covered strings. So having a little difficulty following.

Comment: You should test this function. If you don't know how to do that, watch some youtube videos about the issue or search some documents on google. When I was a student stackoverflow didn't exist, but I still managed to do my homeworks. Try to be more inquisitive and don't be afraid to try new things.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a lesson, I won't give you the solution outright, but I will give you some hints:

1. You're only thinking in `int`. Think in `String` instead. :) This will also take care of the case where users provide you numbers with a large number of digits.
2. You **will** need to validate your input though; what if someone enters "12abc3"?
3. `String.charAt(int)` will be helpful.
4. `Integer.parseInt(String)` will also be helpful.

You could also look at using `long` instead of `int`; `long` has an upper limit of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 though.

Comment: 1. i don't see how string would be applicable as this is only our 4th lesson. I have seen it in other examples but having a hard time following the class. </br>2. yes validate I can understand and put in with the n=long I think would be the right way? Not clear on 3 and 4

Comment: Has your instructor not gone over `String`? Try using `long` instead of `int`, then.

Comment: no we haven't covered String, so am right in that long n; would replace int n;

Comment: Yes, you can use `long`, instead of `int`.

Comment: public class spacing {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            long n;

            System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");

            n = in.nextInt();   
      
                  long sum = 0;          

                  while (n != 0) {

                        sum += n % 10;

                        n /= 10;

                  }
                  System.out.println("Sum of digits: " + sum);

  }
 }

Comment: so there's is the long, but how do i get started on the splitting of the integer? and then for that matter where do i put that in relation to what I have already?

Comment: You're on the right track, as far as splitting the number (by modding and then dividing by 10). Instead of reading in an `int`, you're just going to be reading the value into a `long`. `Scanner` has a `nextLong()` method.

Comment: ?? so something along this: 

nextLong(%n);
%n/10;

Comment: ok wow actually did something right!
so where does that go in relation to what I have already?

Comment: Vivin, I have to leave for work, can we touch base later this evening? Thanks again for the guidance!!

Comment: Impact, I'm not sure what extra guidance I can give you at this point. I think you have more than enough to work with. You're pretty much on the right track. You just need to work on your code a little bit more.